# Can XSS attacker use span,p,label... tags

Tags: asp.net, html, security, xss

I know XSS Attackers use text boxes to inject a script into a page. I want to know if it's possible to use a script on *span*, *p*, *label* elements in a form, and inject it into a page. Should we try to prevent this attack via labels?

Comment: XSS is possible **anywhere** in an HTML page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to remember is that XSS vulnerabilities occur simply by untrusted, unvalidated and unescaped data being rendered anywhere into a webpage. This includes in JavaScript, CSS and literally anywhere within the HTML body.

It doesn't matter if you're generating complete HTML elements of simply setting attributes as it's easy for XSS to break out of the tag it's intended to be rendered in and insert its own markup.

Answer (score 2):

**Any** HTML element is susceptible to XSS attacks, *especially* if you dynamically generate HTML elements from user input.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: If you are using a UI library it's important to know whether the user input you are passing to the UI component will be rendered as HTML or as plain-text - because you only need to escape user input that is passed to the components that actually renders input as HTML.